# how to check if a number exist in a file on a seperate line using python

Tags: python, search, numbers, match

I have a file PhaseMar.txt with each line containing numbers only like

```
4
16
14
44
55
34
```

It is required to check if a certain number let us suppose 16 exists in that file or not.

I am using

```
test_file = open('PhaseMar.txt', 'r')   #modification!
test_lines = test_file.readlines()  #modification!
print test_lines
size =len(test_lines) #[0]
print size
count=0
              for i in xrange(1,size):
               #print int(realID)
               #print int(test_lines[i])
               print (int(test_lines[i])-int(realID))
               if abs(int(test_lines[i])-int(realID))> 0.1:
                count=count+1
               else:
                count=0

               if (count>0):
                print "true" 
               else:
                print "false"
               count=0
```

It checks all the entries 6 times and it is giving me answer of true when the number exists. However, it also prints all the false along with that. I wonder if there is a one-liner existing for this.
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say check for integer 16 in file PhaseMars.txt, quick solution as below but its not memory efficient to handle large file as it need to read whole file into memory

```
check = str(16)
with open('PhaseMars.txt') as f:
    match = check in f.read().splitlines()
    # match will be True if match inside file, False otherwise
```

if you need to handle large file, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) might come in handy, it read each line from file only when needed for processing at each iteration.

Example, lets say we are interested on number more than 16
    import itertools

```
chk = 16
with open(r'PhaseMars.txt') as f:
    # match holding iterator for line that match > 16 predicate
    # replace itertools.ifilter with just filter for python 3
    match = itertools.ifilter(lambda x:int(x.strip()) > chk, f)

    # you may process the match item afterwards 
    for i in match:
        # do your processing of the matching item here
        # for eg. just print them out
        print(i.strip())

    # OR built them into a list
    matchlist = list(match)
```

Comment: it is is not working when the file is large and other than this I must change each integer to string right? Is there a better way since I need to do some arithmetics too.

Comment: you are correct, its not efficient for handling large file, check edited answer if fit your needs :)